# Is this the fastest/pythonian way to use groupby, apply and join?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I am working with a large dataset. I have implemented this solution as a toy model to apply to my data. The function "testFunction" below is just an example of a general function that can contain several variables.

This example is working as I need. My question is if this is the best way to implement it:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def creatingDataFrame():

    raw_data = {'id': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
                'code': [1, 2, 3, 3 , 2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 3],                
                'var1': [10, 20, 30, 40 , 50, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50],
                'var2': [20, 30, 40 , 50, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 10],
                'var3': [30, 40 , 50, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 10, 20]}
    df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['id','code', 'var1', 'var2', 'var3'])
    df.loc[1, 'var1'] = np.nan
    df.loc[8,'var3']=np.nan    

    return df



def testFunction(group,variables):
    return np.mean(group[variables[0]])/np.mean(group[variables[1]])

if __name__ == '__main__':

    df=creatingDataFrame()

    grouped=df.dropna().groupby(['code'])


    data = grouped.apply(testFunction,variables=['var1','var3'])    
    dfData=pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['testFunction2Data'])
    df=df.join(dfData,on='code',rsuffix='_r')
    print df
```

This is the original dataframe:

```
   id  code  var1  var2  var3
0   1     1    10    20    30
1   2     2   NaN    30    40
2   3     3    30    40    50
3   4     3    40    50    10
4   5     2    50    10    20
5   6     1    10    20    30
6   7     2    20    30    40
7   8     1    30    40    50
8   9     3    40    50   NaN
9  10     3    50    10    20
```

This is the modified dataframe with an extra column:

```
   id  code  var1  var2  var3  testFunction2Data
0   1     1    10    20    30           0.454545
1   2     2   NaN    30    40           1.166667
2   3     3    30    40    50           1.500000
3   4     3    40    50    10           1.500000
4   5     2    50    10    20           1.166667
5   6     1    10    20    30           0.454545
6   7     2    20    30    40           1.166667
7   8     1    30    40    50           0.454545
8   9     3    40    50   NaN           1.500000
9  10     3    50    10    20           1.500000
```

Edition:

Question: I need to apply some functions to groups of variables of a large data set and then I need to create new columns in the original dataframe with the results for each group of these functions. In the example above I implemented a solution, but I am not sure if this is the best way to do that, since I am very new in Pandas.

Comment: The moment I find a pandas question that provides code/data/both, I blindly upvote it.

Comment: Though what you want to do isn't clear. The moment you define your own function to send to apply... you're probably doing it wrong... 90% of the time.

Comment: @coldspeed "you define your own function to send to apply... you're probably doing it wrong" You mean that this is a slow way to do that?

Comment: Yes, I believe it is. My answer can only offer improvements based on what I see. If at all possible, further improvements would be possible by seeing your actual data and what you might want to do. But for your toy data, this is probably as good as it gets, with minor tweaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an improvement, you could pass `np.mean` to `DataFrameGroupBy.agg` directly:

```
gp = df.dropna().groupby(['code'])[['var1', 'var3']].agg(np.mean)  
# gp = df.dropna().groupby(['code'])[['var1', 'var3']].agg('mean')
```

Now, divide `var1` by `var3`:

```
gp2 = gp['var1'] / gp['var3']
```

Combine this with a join:

```
 df.join(
    pd.DataFrame(gp['var1'] / gp['var3'], columns=['testFunction2Data']), 
    on='code', 
    rsuffix='_r')

   id  code  var1  var2  var3  testFunction2Data
0   1     1  10.0    20  30.0           0.454545
1   2     2   NaN    30  40.0           1.166667
2   3     3  30.0    40  50.0           1.500000
3   4     3  40.0    50  10.0           1.500000
4   5     2  50.0    10  20.0           1.166667
5   6     1  10.0    20  30.0           0.454545
6   7     2  20.0    30  40.0           1.166667
7   8     1  30.0    40  50.0           0.454545
8   9     3  40.0    50   NaN           1.500000
9  10     3  50.0    10  20.0           1.500000
```